# Alloy view not working with Native ios module

Tags: ios, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules, titanium-proxy

I have developed a native module which requires me to pass a view while opening the module controller. The module is basically a PDF Reader and I need to put a custom sharing button which I need to pass from Titanium code. This button view was visible and working perfectly fine with Classic Titanium apps and also working fine when I programmatically create the button. The only problem is now using Alloy, I created a separate control for the button and now it stopped working.

Below I have pasted snippet for demo code.

Here is my code which was working fine when used programmatic control:

`App.js:`

```
var shareBase = Ti.UI.createView({
width: 40,
height: 40,
top: 0,
left: 0,
backgroundColor: 'green'
});
var shareview = Ti.UI.createView({
backgroundImage: 'shareview.png',
width: 40,
height: 40,
});
shareBase.add(shareView);
...
...
...

// Below is the code how I am passing the view for the module
var PDF_READER = require('com.investis.docreader');
var document = PDF_READER.createPDFDocument(reportFile.nativePath.trim());
...
document.setCustomView(shareBase); // Share view is being passed
document.setTitle(report.title);
document.display();
```

Controller in the module which accepts the view passed from Titanium code:
`controller.m`

```
- (void)setCustomView: (id)args {
    TiUIViewProxy *_argVw = args;
    if (!args) {
        NSLog(@"View Proxy nil", nil);
    }

    [_pdfViewController setCustomView: _argVw.view ];  // _argVw.view gets UIView from ViewProxy
    NSLog(@"View assigned here", nil);
    NSLog([_argVw description], nil);
    NSLog([_argVw.view description], nil);
}
```

`pdfViewController.m - The controller from where original PDF Reader is called, so I need to pass the view to this controller which loads the view into Toolbar`

```
...
_customButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: _customView]; // _customView is the view which is passed from controller.m
...
// Now display button items into toolbar
toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:... _customButton, fixedSpace, ..., nil];
```

The above code was working fine. But when I implemented the code as Alloy controller, the custom view is stopped being loaded from the controller.

`App.js`

```
var pdfshare = Alloy.createController("SocialShare", {});
...
document.setCustomView(pdfshare.getView()); // Passing custom view from the controller, other code in the file remain same
...
```

Here is the code how `SocialShare` is created.
`SocialShare.xml`

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="container" class="container">
        <View id="shareIt" onSingletap="shareIt" platform="ios"/>
        <View id="shareIt" onSingletap="shareItAndroid" platform="android" />
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

`SocialShare.tss`

```
".container":{
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0
},

".container[formFactor=tablet]":{
    height: 43,
    width: 43
},

".container[formFactor=handheld]":{
    height: 40,
    width: 40
}
```

`SocialShare.js`

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
...
// Here nothing extra ordinary UI related tasks are performed. Only event handlers for shareIt
```

The same code at Module side but still it stopped working. If I pass view generated programmatically then it works fine. Let me know if we need to treat Alloy views differently or not. I have searched a lot over Google and read through docs but unable to find any proper solution.

Details:-
Titanium SDK: 3.2.3.GA

Alloy: 1.3.0

iPhone Simulator: 7.1

Let me know if there is any solution around this or any patch.

Comment: Do you have any errors messages?

Comment: I don't have any errors and the app is working fine. Only the view which I pass into module is not being loaded. The view was perfectly being loaded until we convert it to alloy object. Do we need to change module code to handle alloy views? Because the baseview which I pass to the module displays properly but its children gets invisible. I am not changing anything from module or anywhere else. I can't understand why only baseview is visible and skips child views?

Comment: @Origineil how it could not be related to Alloy-UI? The issue has come after I put alloy code for the view.

Comment: [AlloyUI](http://alloyui.com/examples/) is not what you are using.

Comment: ok, here AlloyUI is different than what I think of. :)